# Calculate DPI of image

Tags: image, canvas, printing, dpi

I have an image on a canvas. That image will be resized by user.After that, the canvas content will pe printed at a specific dimension.
I want to calculate the DPI of the resized image, so i can tell the user if he resized to much and the printed quality will be affected.
Does someone know a formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPI means dots per inch.

Divide the pixel size of the image with its physical dimensions in inches.

Comment: that mean the original pixel with of the image devided by the printed image width in inch?